# Show / Hide ad by time at the same time worldwide

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

The idea is like this: At 6:00 am Argentina, I want a announce (image) to be displayed that remains active for one hour, that is, that it can be visible and that when it reaches 60min it is hidden, that is , at 7:00 am hidden. That this action is repeated every 7 hours. Therefore I want it to remain hidden for 7 hours and repeat the action again. At 2:00 p.m. it appears and at 3:00 p.m. it hides. 7 hours pass. It reappears at 10pm and hides at 11pm. 7 hours pass and he appears again at 6:00 am.

I have this code created so that it recognizes the time differences and runs at the same time in all countries, that is, the ad comes out at 6:00 am Argentina and at the same time it is shown in Los Angeles even though it is 2:00 am. But it's not working. It appears at the time according to the country.

NOTE: there are two elements in the code, one is for another ad that appears at 0:00

```js
var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
var horarios1 = [6 + offset, 14 + offset, 22 + offset];
var elemento1 = document.getElementById("panel1");
var horarios2 = [0 + offset];
var elemento2 = document.getElementById("panel2");
setInterval(function() {
 var hora = new Date().getHours();
 if (horarios1.includes((hora + offset) % 24)) {
   elemento1.style.display = 'block';
 } else {
   elemento1.style.display = 'none';
 }
 if (horarios2.includes((hora + offset) % 24)) {
   elemento2.style.display = 'block';
 } else {
   elemento2.style.display = 'none';
 }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="panel1" style="display: none;">PANEL 6, 14, 22</div>
<div id="panel2" style="display: none;">PANEL 0</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using javascript time. Javascript takes the time from users machine. So when you visit your website, it will show your machine's time, when I visit it'll show my machine's time. However if you want a universal time for the whole world, i.e show the ad Argentina time 06:00 all over the world, than you can apply either of the following methods.

**1. USE SERVER TIME**

You need a bit of a backend code here. Show the time from your server, and its fixed for the whole world. Details depend on what backend technology (php/java/python) you are using.

**2. USE A THIRD PARTY API**

Use api from another website. Like [worldtimeapi.org/](http://worldtimeapi.org/). Make an ajax call, get the time of your desired location. You can use plain javascript or use any ajax library to do that. Here I'm including two methods: 1) plain javascript and 2) using [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) (a popular ajax library)

**Vanilla JS**

```
function getTime(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", url);
        req.onload = () =>
            req.status === 200
                ? resolve(req.response)
                : reject(Error(req.statusText));
        req.onerror = (e) => reject(Error(`Network Error: ${e}`));
        req.send();
    });
}
```

Now Use this function to make the ajax call

```
let url = "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires";

getTime(url)
    .then((response) => { //the api will send this response which is a JSON
        // you must parse the JSON to get an object using JSON.parse() method
        let dateObj = JSON.parse(response);
        let dateTime = dateObj.datetime;
        console.log(dateObj);
        console.log(dateTime);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

**AXIOS**

Add axios library to your project.

```
axios({
    url:"http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
    method: "get",
})
    // Here response is an object. The api will send you a JSON. But axios automatically
    // convert it to an object. So you don't need to convert it manually.
    .then((response) => {
        let dateObj = response.data;
        let dateTime = dateObj.datetime;
        console.log(dateObj);
        console.log(dateTime);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

```js
(function () {
 var url =
  "http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires",
  horarios1 = [6, 14, 22],
  elemento1 = document.getElementById("panel1"),
  horarios2 = [0],
  elemento2 = document.getElementById("panel2");

 function getTime(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   req.open("GET", url);
   req.onload = () =>
    req.status === 200
     ? resolve(req.response)
     : reject(Error(req.statusText));
   req.onerror = (e) => reject(Error(`Network Error: ${e}`));
   req.send();
  });
 }

 setInterval(function () {
  getTime(url)
   .then((data) => {
    var dateObj = JSON.parse(data);
    var dateTime = dateObj.datetime;
    var hora = Number(dateTime.slice(11, 13));

    if (horarios1.includes(hora)) {
     elemento1.style.display = "block";
    } else {
     elemento1.style.display = "none";
    }
    if (horarios2.includes(hora)) {
     elemento2.style.display = "block";
    } else {
     elemento2.style.display = "none";
    }
   })
   .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
   });
 }, 1000);
})();
```

```html
  <div id="panel1" style="display: none;">PANEL 6, 14, 22</div>
  <div id="panel2" style="display: none;">PANEL 0</div>
```

Hope that helps. Few Things to remember though -

**1.** [worldtimeapi.org/](http://worldtimeapi.org/) is a third party service. If they choose to terminate their service, your code will break. But if you use your server time, as long as your server is running, your code will run.

**2.** Because of the ajax call, this code will not work in stackoverflow. Copy paste the code in your project to make it work.

**3.** If still it doesn't work, it means you are facing CORS (cross origin policy) issue. [Read this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#:~:text=Cross%2DOrigin%20Resource%20Sharing%20(CORS)%20is%20a%20mechanism%20that,resources%20from%20a%20different%20origin.&text=The%20CORS%20mechanism%20supports%20secure,transfers%20between%20browsers%20and%20servers.), search internet/SO. You will find your solution. Happy coding :)

Comment: Please, How can I do that?
Do I need to add the following line for it to work?
`$datetime = new DateTime('NOW', new DateTimeZone('America/Argentina/Buenos_aires'));
echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: Thanks for answering. Both options seem interesting but I don't know how to apply them. Where I want to put these alerts on a site hosted by Blogger and I really don't know how I can use those two alternatives.

Comment: I assume you are not a javascript pro, and these are a bit advanced concepts. These are not alerts. You will find the result (date and time) in your console. In your chrome press F12 and then click "console" tab. You will find the result there. and you have to put the javascript code inside <script></script> tag.

Comment: I'm not an expert in Javascript, I know the basics and very little. I'm putting the code inside the <script> tag pero no pasa nada. I choose to use the Javascript method, do I add it before the code I create for the elements with their schedules? Or how do I adapt this code that you gave me to make it work in those times that I need? Sorry if i don't understand much

Comment: Follow the code snippet. It should work. Its working in my machine. Happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks for modifying the code. I was nowhere near hahaha. I still can't see it in action so this may be the CORS problem. I will be investigating how I can solve it now.  If you know something that makes it easier for me to solve that, I will be super grateful to you.

Comment: check your console. Is there any error? paste the error here. Lets see if I can help.

Comment: Three errors appear: (1)"Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS."
What I did was add "https" to the http://worldtimeapi URL and I stop getting the error. Still the code doesn't work. 
And also the error appears: (2)"XHR finished loading: GET "https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires"."
and (3) "TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at elemento1.style.display = "none";"

Comment: 2) check your url. click the url from your last answer. you'll see " at the end of the url string. remove it and its working in the browser. how this double quotation mark end up in your url is a mystery though. Remove the " from the end of the url string.

3) It means elemento1 is not found. Did you add panel1 and panel2 div in your HTML? And also place our script tag at the end of the page, just before the closing body tag.

Do these and then let me know the result. :)

Comment: Add the extra quote by mistake in the comment. Sorry. What I did was to modify the calls to "item1 / item2" instead of "panel1 / panel2" in the div so that it would find the item and it worked. The code is working! I am very grateful for helping me achieve this. Thank you. The function takes a few seconds (1.5sec) to appear every time the page is loaded, but I suppose that positioning the <script> in another part of the general site code would make it load even faster. Thank you, thank you very much again.

Comment: Glad that it worked. The function is taking time because of the ajax call. Positioning of the script tag has nothing to do with it. Happy coding :)